# Vue JS fetch data on mount based on props data passed always return false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need to fetch latest data when mount vue component, but need to check the props first. but it allways getting undefined.
it looks like this code

```js
Vue.component('book', {
    props: ["showLatest"],
  data: function() {
    return {
        books: null
    }
  },
  template: '<ul><li v-for="book in books">This is a book {{ book.name }} <small><i>{{ book.publisher}}</i></small></li></ul>',
  method: {
    fetch: function() {
        this.books = [
        {
          name: "Latest 1",
          publisher: "publisher_test1"
        },
        {
          name: "Latest 2",
          publisher: "publisher_test2"
        },
        {
          name: "Latest 3",
          publisher: "publisher_test3"
        }
      ];
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.showLatest);
    if(!this.showLatest) {
            this.books = [
        {
          name: "Test 1",
          publisher: "publisher_test1"
        },
        {
          name: "Test 2",
          publisher: "publisher_test2"
        },
        {
          name: "Test 3",
          publisher: "publisher_test3"
        }
      ];
    } else {
        this.fetch();
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Digital Library!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <book :showLatest="true"></book>
</div>
```

Why `showLatest` always getting `undefined`. if this is not good approach, how to make it work..?
Hopefully anyone can help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is better to add a `watcher` for `showLatest` and fetch the data from there, so that anytime `showLatest` changed a new data will be fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop should be written in kebab-case format when it's used in parent like `<book :show-latest="true"></book>` or just `<book show-latest></book>` and in the child component fix `method` to `methods` :

```js
Vue.component('book', {
    props: ["showLatest"],
  data: function() {
    return {
        books: null
    }
  },
  template: '<ul><li v-for="book in books">This is a book {{ book.name }} <small><i>{{ book.publisher}}</i></small></li></ul>',
  methods: {
    fetch: function() {
        this.books = [
        {
          name: "Latest 1",
          publisher: "publisher_test1"
        },
        {
          name: "Latest 2",
          publisher: "publisher_test2"
        },
        {
          name: "Latest 3",
          publisher: "publisher_test3"
        }
      ];
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.showLatest);
    if(!this.showLatest) {
            this.books = [
        {
          name: "Test 1",
          publisher: "publisher_test1"
        },
        {
          name: "Test 2",
          publisher: "publisher_test2"
        },
        {
          name: "Test 3",
          publisher: "publisher_test3"
        }
      ];
    } else {
        this.fetch();
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Digital Library!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <book :show-latest="true"></book>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Boussadjra Brahim. it's totally work

Comment: One thing to be noted is that, you wont face this limitation in Single File Components.